# I need help understanding character manipulation

Tags: c, character, lowercase

Question: I need to write a function,

```
int is_lower_101(char c),
```

that returns true if it's a lowercase and false otherwise. And I can't use the predefined `tolower` type functions. I also can't use integer values for the characters.

What I need help with: I already have the header file:

```
#ifndef CHAR_H
#define CHAR_H

int is_lower_101(char c);

#endif
```

But I'm having trouble on the implementation file. I'm not sure what the general format for an implementation file involving characters looks like. I have a feeling I have to use conditionals, but I'm just not sure how I would show that `c` is a lowercase character. Would I use a for loop? Thanks.

Comment: But, wouldn't that be using the integer values of the characters? I can't do that. :(

Comment: If this is an assignment, I'd recommend asking if é, æ, ñ, and ü are lowercase or not.  (Not to mention Ꮉ, Ꮍ, Ꮝ, Ꮞ, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about supporting any characters other than `a` through `z`, then you can do a comparison like:

```
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
```

Note that this is a very bad idea and will break the first time someone types résumé, etc.  The standard functions are there for this reason.

Comment: Are the standard functions the tolower type functions that I can't use in this assignment?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to ask, should `islower("résumé")` return `true` or `false`!

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee that only lowercase letters have values between `'a'` and `'z'`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Very true, which is why rolling your own function is a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

```
int is_lower_101(char c){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        if("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[i] == c)
            return i==i;
    }
    return i!=i;
}
```

use bsearch ver.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return *((char*)a) - *((char*)b);
}

int is_lower_101(char c){
    return !!bsearch(&c, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 26, sizeof(char), cmp);
}
```

Comment: Is it okay if I do this without using a for loop? And one quick question, are character literals just: 'a', 'b', etc.?

Comment: @KarenLee I don't understand the meaning of the your question.

Comment: So, is it okay if I did this with just a conditional statement that says: if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') then return true? And what are character literals? Are those just the characters without the integer values?

Comment: `if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') then return true? ` yes. but a character other than az is included as a possibility exists.

Comment: If my instructor only wants us to include characters a-z, then would it be fine if I did it the way I did?

Comment: I think it depends on the instructor. It is because there is no problem for most systems.

Comment: @KarenLee character literals: e.g. `'a'`, `'\t'`, `'"'`, `'\377'` etc. start `'` and character order and end `'`, and All characters are treated as an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that is independent of the character set encoding, but it only supports locales in which the only lowercase letters are the 26 lowercase Latin letters (which includes the default C locale).

It takes more data space than other implementations in answers here, since it requires a table, but it should be very fast, requiring only a few instructions to zero-extend its parameter, load the address of the table, and look up the result.

```
#include <limits.h>

int is_lower_101(char a)
{
    static char t[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {
        [(unsigned char) 'a'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'b'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'c'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'd'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'e'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'f'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'g'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'h'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'i'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'j'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'k'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'l'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'm'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'n'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'o'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'p'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'q'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'r'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 's'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 't'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'u'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'v'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'w'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'x'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'y'] = 1,
        [(unsigned char) 'z'] = 1,
    };
    return t[(unsigned char) a];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For ensuring is the character lowercase or not, use ASCII table. 
http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif 
So if character code is between 97 and 122 - it's lowercase

Comment: Karen cannot use integer values in determining the character is lower case or not. I too missed that part.

Comment: Yeah, I can't use integer values. :(

Comment: Yea, now I understand, so, can you use for example byte instead of integers? That would work like a cheat :)

Comment: Byte instead of integers? Sorry, I'm new to programming.

Comment: I meant type char which is 1 byte long. If you declare 'unsigned char' variable the range of it would be 0..255, enough for working with characters. But I'm not sure this is what you need

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee that characters are encoded with ASCII or that only lowercase letters have values between `'a'` and `'z'`.